# Refresh opener window

Tags: javascript

I have a window that opens a new window with `window.open`.

When I want to reload/refresh the main page with

```
window.opener.location="index.php"
```

(or many other tests, reload, etc.)

Instead of refreshing the opening page, a new window is opened with index.php, or I get Permission Denied (in IE)

This is driving me nuts!

Thanks

Comment: window.opener.location.reload() gives a PERMISSION DENIED error

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
window.opener.location.reload()
```

Comment: Yep, thats when I get PERMISSION DENIED

Comment: @michael check this link: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/3056.htm maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: In my case both FIREFOX and IE7 or IE8 return the same message PERMISSION DENIED!

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.opener.location.href = 'index.php'`, it should be OK.